# Keyboard issue with Batman Arkham Asylum

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-asylum

I bought Arkham Asylum (GotY edition) from Steam. It loads normally but after starting the story mode and watching the first cutscene, none of my keyboard keys work. The escape key still works but nothing else will make Batman move or do anything.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a controller attached to your computer, would you?

Answer (score 3):

I am quite certain, and as Frank pointed out, you would be having a controller attached to your computer. If you want to use the keyboard, simply plug it out.

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as the comment Frank made.

Comment: But a comment is not an answer

Comment: In my experience @Pribhat's answer is correct.  I frequently have a controller plugged in for other games and if I forget to remove it, Arkham Asylum will not work (or will start but spin the camera constantly)